# Use Mobile menu (burger) on mobile and tablet sizes for a foundation 5 site

Tags: html, css, zurb-foundation, zurb-foundation-5

I'm sure this has been asked but I can't seem to find an example that isn't using SASS. I just have a regular CSS file that I'm working with. I want the burger menu to change to the horizontal menu on the larger size.(`@media only screen and (min-width: 64.063em)`) I've seen a few posts saying to update the settings.scss file like this(http://foundation.zurb.com/forum/posts/1483-customize-topbar-breakpoint-in-scss) but again I'm not using SASS for this project. I just can't seem to figure out what is triggering the menu to change from mobile to desktop: media queries or javascript.

Comment: You are going to run into more headaches getting it working by overriding Foundation's default CSS than you would if you just upgraded your project to use Foundation Sass. Probably not what you want to hear but the small amount of work put into making the switch to Foundation Sass will pay off in the long run.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to use CSS you can override the Foundation CSS in a separate CSS file (ie:`styles.css`) section that follows the `foundation.css`

[Demo on Codeply](http://www.codeply.com/go/OtVVMn0n6V)

```
@media only screen and (max-width: 64.063em) {
    .top-bar {
      overflow: hidden;
      height: 2.8125rem;
      line-height: 2.8125rem;
      position: relative;
      background: #333;
      margin-bottom: 0;
    }

    .top-bar-section {
      left: 0;
      position: relative;
      width: auto;
      transition: left 300ms ease-out;
    }

    .top-bar-section ul {
      padding: 0;
      width: 100%;
      height: auto;
      display: block;
      font-size: 16px;
      margin: 0;
    }

    .top-bar .toggle-topbar.menu-icon {
      top: 50%;
      margin-top: -16px;
      display:block;
    }
    .top-bar .title-area {
      float: none;
    }
}
```

http://codeply.com/go/OtVVMn0n6V

Comment: This method disables the mobile menu form working. Same is true in your demo file.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to use SASS, then you'd better change foundation.css file.

Around line 1682 change it from

```
meta.foundation-mq-topbar {
  font-family: "/only screen and (min-width:40.063em)/";
  width: 40.063em;
}
```

to

```
meta.foundation-mq-topbar {
  font-family: "/only screen and (min-width:64.063em)/";
  width: 64.063em;
}
```

Also around line 2006, change it from

```
@media only screen and (min-width: 40.063em) {
```

To

```
@media only screen and (min-width: 64.063em) {
```

Comment: The burger menu is disabled when I change these numbers